# Apache equivalent to IIS application pool

Tags: php, apache, application-pool

I have an Apache server, and there are many sites in it. One or two of these sites are consuming the whole server's resources, consuming almost all the MPM processes, which leads to the server failing and all the other sites becoming very slow.

Is it possible to implement something like an [application pool in IIS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735247%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) in Apache server to avoid other sites becoming slow when one site is consuming all the server resources?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware there is no strict equivalent to application pools in Apache, however you can accomplish splitting by running different httpds as http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DifferentUserIDsUsingReverseProxy describes:

"One frequently requested feature is to run different virtual hosts under different userids. Unfortunately, due to the basic nature of unix permission handling, this is impossible. (Although it is possible to run CGI scripts under different userids using suexec or cgiwrap.) You can, however, get the same effect by running multiple instances of Apache httpd and using a reverse proxy to bring them all into the same name space. "